# Hadamard and Golay sequences reference request

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

Please can someone recommend a good introductory book that covers Walsh-Hadamard codes, and Golay complementary sequences (in particular in relation to their merit factors and other correlation properties). Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Sloane's book?

Comment: there is no aperiodic correlation treatment in McWilliams and Sloane.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find this topic treated at an introductory level in books.

Have a look at the book *Difference sets, sequences and their correlation properties*, edited by A. Pott, P. V. Kumar, T. Helleseth and D. Jungnickel,  Nato Science Series, Series C: vol. 542, Kluwer academic press, 1999.

Google books has a good preview. Sol Golomb's overview chapter on correlation and Hoholdt's chapter on Merit factor are excellent places to start.

Schroeder's *Number Theory in Science and Communication
With Applications in Cryptography, Physics, Digital Information, Computing, and Self-Similarity*, from Springer, is an excellent book that will have a few chapters which will interest you.